# Can I reset all the simulator (and app) settings using the console command without restart the simulator?

Tags: ios, automated-tests, ios-simulator, xcode8

I can reinstall the app, but I do not want to restart the simulator. So, I can not use these solutions:

```
xcrun simctl erase {deviceId}
```

or

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/*
```

or

> https://github.com/mpatzer/ResetAllSimulators

How else can I reset my app settings?

Comment: you could just delete the app's folder inside the simulator's directory

Comment: @Dmitry so I will reset the app settings. But not a simulator.

Answer (score 0):

This can now be accomplished with `xcrun simctl erase all`